# In Ruby on Rails, how can I map all actions in a controller to root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Ruby on Rails, how can I do the equivalent of this in a more elegant routes line? I may have to add many of these...

```
  map.connect '/about', :controller => "site", :action => "about"
  map.connect '/contact', :controller => "site", :action => "contact"
  map.connect '/preview', :controller => "site", :action => "preview"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
map.connect '/:action', :controller => "site", :action => /about|contact|preview/
```

The part `:action => /about|contact|preview/` makes sure that only the listed words can be used as `action` in this route,.

Answer (score 0):

But do not forget to move the route suggested by @Tomas to the bottom of your routes.rb
Otherwise it will catch routes that should not be caught.

Comment: It won't catch everything if you use it with the regular expression condition.